# Display other entries from same category on single-entry page

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, categories

I have a single-entry page with no category information in the URL. Each entry is only assigned to one category (or, if multiple, I only need one).

The goal is to display a list of up to 5 other entries from the same channel and category.

I've been around and around this but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you given this a shot?

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode

It's meant specifically for single-entry pages. I think it's used something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1"}

    Our single entry page ! {title}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:channel:entries related_categories_mode="yes" limit="5" channel="CHANNEL_ID"}

     Related entries!

 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

It that works for you, **please** take that inner loop out and put it in an embedded template, as it's more efficient.

Comment: How have I managed to overlook this for so long?! Thanks, yes, that worked perfectly. (Well, it actually it can't be nested inside another channel entries tag, but once I fixed that it worked exactly as expected.)